# The react component resets accidentally

Tags: reactjs, reset, react-component, react-state

Is there any special condition, that causes a react component to reset completely (not just re-render)?

*What do I mean by **reset**?*

**Reverting back ALL STATES to their default values (that given in `useState()`) and re-running all my `useEffect()` callbacks (even with empty dependency-list (`[]`)) … LIKE ANOTHER OR A NEW COMPONENT!**

---

This wonderful event happens for one of my components during its lifetime (after a lot of correct re-rendering for this component and other components). I don't know why! And I thought this is an impossible event in React:

```js
export default function Project (props) {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState(false)
  const tempRef = useRef(false)
  console.debug({ temp }, tempRef)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug('INITIALIZATION:', { temp }, tempRef)
    setTemp(true)
    tempRef.current = true
  }, [])

  // ...
}
```

[image]

---

I'm suspicious of `react-router-dom@6.0.0-beta.8` that I used in my project. But I can't change it, because of the scale of the project and a lot of usage of it.

---

UPDATE: All parents of this component are working as expected. Even after this event (for this component).

Comment: Which kind of `props` comes from parents? you can try with `React.memo()` hooks.
Might be possible your` props` were changed and the entire component was re-render.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: @Asifvora; As far as I know, these things control re-rending of the component, not FULLY RESETTING it!

Comment: but if something caused re-render, we would see in the console, that `temp` became `true` again. Here I see it stopped on "INITIALIZATION" console and didn't change the state again, that's weird

Comment: Could you please show your some code

Comment: Do you use `key` for this component or any of its parent? If you do, changing the key will cause this.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, No. Explicitly no. But `react-router-dom` may do that. I don't know.

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili You need to use profiler to detect why your component has been recreated. This might also help https://medium.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render-mr-big-pure-react-component-2a36dd86996f

Comment: we would need more context around usage, where is it rendered? React uses a key (mostly in lists, or components rendered in some iteration method) to determine whether to update/unmount/mount a component. So this situation (unmount, mount) is typically a key issue. If you are passing in a key, pass the same value to a different prop (such as, checkKey) and then console log it in the mount useEffect to check that it is not changing. If it is not, its possibly higher up the parent tree.